# What kind of butterfly is this one?

Tags: identification, butterflies

This one seems to be from the era of black-white telavision :), but still I a kind of like it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about an insect that's **affecting** your garden. Please see https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12/are-questions-about-birds-and-other-animals-in-your-garden-on-topic for our policy about these types of questions.

Comment: There are two other Stack Exchange sites that accept species identification questions, [biology.se] and [outdoors.se], but we all require more information in the question as to your climate and/or location in the world and the habitat that the insect was found in.

Comment: But, it is affecting the garden. Can you elaborate more your claim that this butterfly is not affecting the garden?

Comment: Secondly, the criterium that the animal should affect the garden is ill-conceived: How can one know if an animal affects the garden, if one does not know what that animal is?? You created one of the stupidest rules that I ever heard.

Comment: https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/39860/identify-this-bug This was the question the other day. Why is that question ok, and this one not?? Tell me the reason. I demand impartiality! Many other questions from the past - the same. Riles should  be applied all the time, not depending on the someones mood.

Comment: Biting insects damage plants.  Butterflies eat nectar and lay eggs.  Same with moths.  You need to find a caterpillar of this insect to be on topic!

Comment: But, how can I find its caterpilar, if I don't know its kind?  At least you admit that butterflies were caterpillars. And from Gardening 101: Everything affects everything. Do you realize how absurd the 'affect' rule is?

Comment: There are some very fine distinctions, and it's pointless arguing with anyone in comments.  You can make your case in meta instead.  Or, if you want an answer, just repost to biology. But just because an animal lands on a plant, tree, grass or whatever that grows on your land does not automatically make it on topic for gardening!

Comment: Alexsandar M, chat is another good place to discuss policy and get explanations. Just go into [chat], and ping a mod, like Niall C.. Other experienced users are there too and can help you. Discussions need to be friendly, of course, but are always welcome. It can help ease frustration and make your time here more comfortable. Comments on the site that are sarcastic or possibly offensive to others will be removed, so polite discourse in chat is really the best way to be heard. I highly recommend it!

Comment: Who wrote 'the affect rule'?

Comment: If you're in North America, it's either a Tiger Swallowtail or a Zebra Swallowtail. These are not considered to be pests.

Comment: Rules are normally written by the community in the definition stage.